# How to mark a contact as a favorite from my android app?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to make a contact as a favorite from the app which will be applied to default Android device's contact book.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the `Contacts.STARRED` field with a value of "1":

```
private void starContact(int contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(Contacts.STARRED, "1"); // put "0" for false
    int update = getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
    // if update == 1 the action was successful 
}
```